# JFrame becomes blank and "hang"

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

when the method newWaitScreen is called after the StartGameButtonListener is called the JFrame will be white and "hang", however if newWaitScreen is called before the StartGameButtonListener it shows successfully. Would anyone be able to help me out here?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the mess, this is my first time posting. My code is as follows:

```
public void serverMenu () 
{
    frame = new JFrame ("Game Server");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

    String [] noOfPlayer = {"1", "2", "3"};

    JPanel panel = new JPanel (); 

    JLabel port = new JLabel ("Port");
    portNo = new JTextField (15);

    JLabel players = new JLabel ("No. of Player(s):");
    playerNo = new JComboBox (noOfPlayer);

    JButton startGame = new JButton ("Start Game Server");
    startGame.addActionListener (new StartGameButtonListener());

    panel.add (port);
    panel.add (portNo);
    panel.add (players); 
    panel.add (playerNo); 
    panel.add (startGame);

    frame.add (panel); 
    frame.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (275,200));
    frame.pack (); 
    frame.setVisible (true); 
    //newWaitScreen (444, 2);  //if newWaitScreen is called here, the screen will be shown with no issue

}

private class StartGameButtonListener implements ActionListener 
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
    {
        String portNum = portNo.getText(); 

        String playerNum = (String) playerNo.getSelectedItem(); 

        startGameCallBack (portNum, playerNum);
    }
}

public void startGameCallBack (String portNum, String playerNum)
{
    frame.setVisible (false); 

    int port ; 
    int noPlayer; 

    port = Integer.parseInt (portNum); 

    noPlayer = Integer.parseInt (playerNum);

    waitGame (port, noPlayer); 
}

public void waitGame (int portNum, int noOfPlayer)
{ 
    newWaitScreen (portNum, noOfPlayer);  //if newWaitScreen called JFrame becomes white and "hang"

    ServerSocket serverSocket = null; 

    try 
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket (portNum);
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println ("Port " + portNum +" not avaliable");
        System.exit (0); 
    }

    for (int i = 1 ; i <= noOfPlayer; i++)
    {
        Socket clientSocket = null; 

        try 
        {
            System.out.println ("Waiting for client connection");
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); 
            System.out.println ("Client connected");
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println ("Client unable to connect");
            System.exit (0); 
        }

        System.out.println (i);


        /*ClientHandler c = new ClientHandler (clientSocket, serverCounter); 
        serverCounter++;

        if (serverCounter >= noOfPlayer)
            break;*/
    }
}

public void newWaitScreen (int portNum, int noOfPlayer)
{
    frame = new JFrame ("Game Server");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

    bigPanel = new JPanel ();
    bigPanel.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (200, 300));

    JLabel label = new JLabel ("Listening to port: " + portNum);
    JPanel portLabel = new JPanel ();
    portLabel.add (label);
    bigPanel.add (portLabel); 

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel (); 
    panel1.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (200, 30));

    player1 = new JLabel ("Player 1");
    connection1 = new JLabel ("Waiting for connection...");
    panel1.add (player1);
    panel1.add (connection1);
    bigPanel.add (panel1); 

    if (noOfPlayer > 1)
    {
        player2 = new JLabel ("Player 2");
        connection2 = new JLabel ("Waiting for connection...");

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel (); 
        panel2.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (200, 30));
        panel2.add (player2);
        panel2.add (connection2); 

        bigPanel.add (panel2); 
    }

    if (noOfPlayer > 2)
    {
        player3 = new JLabel ("Player 3");
        connection3 = new JLabel ("Waiting for connection...");
        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel (); 
        panel3.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (200, 30));
        panel3.add (player3);
        panel3.add (connection3); 

        bigPanel.add (panel3); 
    }

   frame.add (bigPanel);
   bigPanel.setVisible (true); 

   frame.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (275,300));
   frame.pack(); 
   frame.setVisible (true); 

   frame.repaint(); 
   frame.revalidate(); 

}
```

Comment: Google `Java JFrame freezing` and find all the duplicate questions. The solution's the same -- use background threads. Good thing to do this sort of search *before* asking a question that has been asked *many* times before.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the UI Thread to listen for the connections on your ServerSocket. You need to create a new Thread to handle this